# Using multiple required_if in a validation rule

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have a `select` with many options, I want another `select` to be required when the first has an specific value.

```
    <select id="category" name="category">
            <option value="a">Option A</option>
            <option value="b">Option B</option>
            <option value="c">Option C</option>
            <option value="d">Option D</option>
            <option value="e">Option E</option>
            <option value="f">Option F</option>
    </select>

    <select id="subcategory" name="subcategory">
            <option value="a">Suboption A </option>
            <option value="b">Suboption B </option>
            <option value="c">Suboption C </option>
            <option value="d">Suboption D </option>
            <option value="e">Suboption E </option>
    </select>
```

I want the second `select` to be required when the user chooses option a,b or f. Is it correct to use the next rule in the controller code that validates the inputs?:

```
    $rules = array(
            'category' => 'alpha|in:a,b,c,d,e,f|required|size:1',
            'subcategory' => 'alpha|
                              in:a,b,f|
                              required_if:category,a|
                              required_if:category,b|
                              required_if:category,f|
                              size:1'
    );
```

Is there (another or) a better way to validate this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that array?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that this is the array corresponding to the validation rules inside the controller code. I was being guided by the [documentation on the Laravel site](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-required-if) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may register a custom validation rule to check this, for example:

```
Validator::extend('required_if_anyOfThese', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // Check here whether any of those Inputs are available and make sure
    // what to do, return true or false depending on the result

    $attribute is field name "subcategory"
    $value will contain the value of the field
    $parameters will contain the parameters, array => a,b,f

});
```

Use it as:

```
$rules = array('subcategory' => 'required_if_anyOfThese:a,b,f');
```

Read more on [Laravel Website](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: What's the best place to put the new validation rule? Should I add this to the original Validator class in the source?

Comment: For other people who wants to know, according to the book [Laravel: Code Bright](http://leanpub.com/codebright), there isn't an standard location for new rules. Also, if you can't get access to the book check [this post](http://anchetawern.github.io/blog/2012/12/25/extending-laravels-validation-class/).

Comment: using MohitMamoria's example is preferable to writing a new rule, as a new rule wouldn't be needed for the OP's issue.

Answer (score 27):

Or, you can simply use it like so.

```
$rules = array('subcategory' => 'required_if:category,a,b,f');
```

Laravel takes all the parameters except the first one as array and then checks if the value of first parameter is matched with the rest of parameters using `in_array` method.

Comment: yes. The validation works. But error message is always "The category field is required when type is a" for b and f category inputs

Comment: Yes. That is the bug in the code, for which I've also sent a pull request to Taylor long back. Here's the pull request: [https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5262](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5262). If he merges it quickly, the bug would be solved. You may comment on the issue on github so that he puts this request on a little good priority.

Comment: The pull request has been merged now. So, better messages too.

Comment: Also, we can use custom error messages: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-error-messages